# Successfully connecting to XMPP via BOSH, but chat window is only updating when I send something

Tags: xmpp, openfire, converse.js

I have tried to connect to an OpenFire XMPP server via either [converse.js](https://conversejs.org/) or [JSXC](https://www.jsxc.org/); in both cases, the client connects successfully, but while they can send messages with no problem, they cannot receive messsages, or, more specifically, they only receive messages from another connected user when they send something.

So far, I have tried implementing BOSH support via [JabberHTTPBind](http://stefan-strigler.de/jhb/),via [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) (proxying to OpenFire's BOSH implementation) and, just to isolate if the filter/servlet is the culprit, I have also tried placing the clients directly under `/openfire/resources/spank/`, so that they would be served in the same host/port as OpenFire's `/http-binding/`; in each case, the weird behavior was the same.

Does someone have any idea of what could be causing that 'write-only' behavior?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know it help you

```
<script>
    converse.initialize({
        allow_otr: true,
        auto_list_rooms: false,
        auto_subscribe: false,
        bosh_service_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind',
        debug: true ,
        hide_muc_server: false,
        i18n: locales['en'],
        prebind: false,
        show_controlbox_by_default: true,
        xhr_user_search: true,
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is weird...

It looks like it you have at least *one* Pidgin instance *anywhere* connected to the server via BOSH, it prevents BOSH from working for everyone regardless of client; at least, it seemed to be my case.

Reconfiguring Pidgin to not use BOSH made both Converse.js and JSXC work correctly.